# How to compute the orthogonal complement of a matrix given an inner product.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Suppose $v_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
                -4 \\
                1 \\
                2
            \end{bmatrix}$, $v_2 = 
            \begin{bmatrix}
                0 \\
                -1 \\
                2
            \end{bmatrix}, S = \{v_1, v_2\}$, and
\begin{align*}\langle x,y \rangle := a_1b_1 + 4a_2b_2 + a_3b_3\end{align*} is an inner product on $\mathbb{R}^3$, compute for a basis of $S^{\bot}$.

According to my understanding, $S^{\bot}$, also known as the orthogonal complement, is basically the null space (Am I right on that?), so I want to know if my solution and conclusion is correct:

First, I performed elementary row operations to get the RREF:
\begin{align*}
\text{RREF: } \begin{bmatrix}
                1 & 0 \\
                0 & 1 \\
                0 & 0
            \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
Solving the matrix equation:
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    x_1 \\
    x_2
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\
    0 \\
    0 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
Since the system has a unique solution, the null space is $\begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\
    0 
\end{bmatrix}$. Hence, $S^{\bot}$ has no basis.

Attempt to Fred's suggestion:
\begin{align*}
\text{Let }v &= \begin{bmatrix}
                x \\
                y \\
                z
              \end{bmatrix}\\\\
\langle v, v_1 \rangle &= x(-4) + 4y(1) + z(2)\\
&= -4x + 4y + 2z\\\\
\langle v, v_2 \rangle &= x(0) + 4y(-1) + z(2)\\
&= -4y + 2z\\\\
\langle v, v_1 \rangle &= \langle v, v_2\rangle\\
-4x+4y+2z &= -4y+2z\\
-4x+8y &= 0\\\\
\text{Let }x = 1&:\\
-4(1) + 8y &= 0\\
-4 + 8y &= 0\\
y &= \dfrac{1}{2}\\\\
-4y + 2z &= 0\\
-2 + 2z &= 0\\
z &= 1
\end{align*}
Hence, $v = \begin{bmatrix}
                1 \\
                1/2 \\
                1
              \end{bmatrix}$ is a basis of $S^{\bot}$

Answer (score 2):

We have that $ \dim S=2$ and

$$ \mathbb R^3=S \oplus S^{\perp}.$$

Hence $ \dim S^{\perp}=1.$  This gives that $S^{\perp}= \{\alpha v: \alpha \in \mathbb R^3\}$ with $v \ne 0.$

Hence you have to determine a vector $v \in \mathbb R^3$ such that $v \ne 0$ and $\langle v,v_1 \rangle = \langle v,v_2 \rangle=0.$

Comment: What do you mean by $v \neq 0$?

Comment: I mean $v \ne (0,0,0)^T.$

Comment: I understand what you are saying. I have to find $v$ such that $\langle v,v_1\rangle$ and  $\langle v,v_2\rangle$ are both equal to 0, without $v$ being equal to $\begin{bmatrix}
                        0 \\
                        0 \\0
                    \end{bmatrix}$. Can you guide me as to how to do that? I understand the process but I have no clue how to get $v$.

Comment: Hi, please check my post, I updated it with my attempt. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: That is correct.