# Finding the orthogonal complement of a span?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, orthogonal-matrices

Let $V = P_3(\mathbb{R})$ the vector space of all polynomials in $t$ of degree at most 3.

$W = M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R})$ the vector space of all $2\times 2$ real matrices.

Define $T:V \rightarrow W$ by $T(a_1 + a_2t + a_3t^2 + a_4t^3) = \begin{bmatrix}
                \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1}}a_1 & \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}a_2 \\
                \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{4}}a_4 & \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}a_3
                \end{bmatrix}$.

**My question:**

2. Let $U = span\left(\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}1 & 2\\ 0 & 3\end{bmatrix}\right\}\right)$, find $U^\bot$.

Is my attempt correct?

Using Gram-schmidt process to get a set of orthonormal basis of $M_2$ with $u_1, u_2$ as given.

Denoting $M$ as $a_{11}E_{11} + a_{12}E_{12} + a_{21}E_{21} + a_{22}E_{22}$, and denoting 2 matrices given as column vectors $(\alpha_1, \alpha_2)$, as the new matrtix $A$, solve $A'x = 0$ and orthonormalize the new basis, we get:
\begin{align*}
                A = \begin{pmatrix}
                        1 & 1\\
                        0 & 0\\
                        0 & 2\\
                        1 & 3
                    \end{pmatrix}
            \end{align*}
Performing elementary row operations on $\begin{bmatrix}
                            1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
                            1 & 0 & 2 & 3
            \end{bmatrix}$, we get the RREF:
\begin{align*}
                \begin{bmatrix}
                                1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\0 & 0 & 1 & 0
                \end{bmatrix}
            \end{align*}
To find the null space, we solve the matrix equation
\begin{align*}
                \begin{bmatrix}
                                1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
                                0 & 0 & 1 & 0
                \end{bmatrix}
                \begin{bmatrix}
                                x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4
                \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
                                0\\0
                \end{bmatrix}
            \end{align*}
We take $x_2 = 2$, $x_4 = s$, then $x_1 = -s$, $x_3 = 0$. Hence,
\begin{align*}
                \vec{x} = \begin{bmatrix}
                                -s\\t\\0\\s
                \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
                                0\\1\\0\\0
                \end{bmatrix} t + \begin{bmatrix}
                                -1\\0\\0\\1
                \end{bmatrix}s
            \end{align*}
By solving $A^Tx = 0$, the orthogonal complement $U^\bot$ is:
\begin{align*}
                \left\{\begin{bmatrix}
                    0\\1\\0\\0
                \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
                    -1\\0\\0\\1
                \end{bmatrix}
                \right\}
            \end{align*}

Comment: What has the first sentence to do with the rest of the question?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure. The problem starts with the first sentence, then a series of sub problems follow. I omitted the other sub-problems. In my attempt, I did not use any information from the first sentence.

Comment: In order to talk about $U^\perp$ for $U\subset M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb R)$ you need to specify an inner product on $M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb R)$ first. Please [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4176502/edit) your post to include that information.

Comment: That's actually the first sub problem, and I omitted it. But since you've asked for it. I'll update my post.

Comment: If you look to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4144237/715008 the question is similar but the inner product is defined. What you need is inner product for W. The inner product you have added is for V and does not relate to this exercise

Comment: Updated my post with the relationship of $V$ and $W$.

Comment: If you only want to find $U^\perp$ in $M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb R)$, why do you even mention the space $V$? It is completely irrelevant to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$u\in U\Rightarrow u=\alpha\cdot \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}+\beta\cdot\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\0&3\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\alpha+\beta&2\beta\\0&\alpha+3\beta\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}a_1&\frac{a_2}{\sqrt{2}}\\\frac{a_4}{2}&\frac{a_3}{\sqrt{3}}\end{bmatrix}, \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb R$$

$$\begin{array}{rrlrlr}u\rightarrow p&=&a_1+a_2t+a_3t^2+a_4t^3\\p&=&(\alpha+\beta)+2\sqrt{2}\beta t+\sqrt{3}(\alpha+3\beta)t^2\\ q\in V, q&=&x_1+x_2t+x_3t^2+x_4t^3 \end{array}$$

$$<p,q>=0\Rightarrow (\alpha+\beta)x_1+\sqrt{2}\beta x_2+\frac{(\alpha+3\beta)x_3}{\sqrt{3}}=0$$

$$\alpha\left(x_1+\frac{x_3}{\sqrt{3}}\right)+\beta(x_1+\sqrt{2}x_2+\sqrt{3}x_3)=0$$

$$x_1=s, x_3=-s\sqrt{3}, x_2=\sqrt{2}s, x_4=r, s, r\in \mathbb R$$

$$q=s+\sqrt{2}st-s\sqrt{3}t^2+rt^3$$

$$T(q)=\begin{bmatrix}s&s\\\frac{r}{2}&-s\end{bmatrix}=s\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}+r\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$$

$$U^\bot=span\left(\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&-1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix}\right)(\therefore)$$

Comment: The exercise is incomplete without the-now removed - definition of inner product: $$a,b\in V:<a,b>=\int_0^1{a_1b_1+a_2b_2t+a_3b_3t^2+a_4b_4t^3dt}$$

Comment: Some people say that that is irrelevant in the problem. So it is relevant?

Comment: Up until now the OP did not specify an inner product on $W$. Without it, you can't compute orthogonal complements in $W$.

Comment: What do you mean? He indeed placed the one thing I removed.

Comment: As I said: You never gave a definition of an inner product on $M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb R)$.